# OverrideAuthorizationAttribute in ASP.NET 5

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to implement the following in MVC6:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Shopper")]
public class HomeController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Editor"), OverrideAuthorization]
    public IActionResult EditPage() {}
}
```

But OverrideAuthorizationAttribute no longer exists. So how do you set it so that a user only needs to be in the `Editor` role and not `Editor` and `Shopper` role to access EditPage in MVC6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/02/overriding-filters-asp-net-mvc-6/) from **Filip W** that explains how write your own solution using the filter providers.

However the framework has changed a lot and his solution has to be updated to take into account the changes in the framework up to **beta8**.

First you will create a new attribute where you can specify the type of the **filter** that you want to override. (In your case this would be the `AuthorizeFilter`)

```
public class OverrideFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

If you want. you could create more specific filters like:

```
public class OverrideAuthorization : OverrideFilter
{
    public OverrideAuthorization()
    {
        this.Type = typeof(AuthorizeFilter);
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a new `IFilterProvider`.

1. This filter provider will be executed after the default providers in
   the framework have run.
2. You can inspect the
   `FilterProviderContext.Results` and search for your `OverrideFilter`
3. If found, you can then inspect the rest of the filters, and delete
   any filter that is of the filtered type and a lower scope

For example create a new `OverrideFriendlyFilterProvider` following this idea:

```
public class OverrideFriendlyFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    //all framework providers have negative orders, so ours will come later
    public int Order => 1;

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors != null)
        {
            //Does the action have any OverrideFilter?
            var overrideFilters = context.Results.Where(filterItem => filterItem.Filter is OverrideFilter).ToArray();
            foreach (var overrideFilter in overrideFilters)
            {                    
                context.Results.RemoveAll(filterItem =>
                    //Remove any filter for the type indicated in the OverrideFilter attribute
                    filterItem.Descriptor.Filter.GetType() == ((OverrideFilter)overrideFilter.Filter).Type &&
                    //Remove filters with lower scope (ie controller) than the override filter (i.e. action method)
                    filterItem.Descriptor.Scope < overrideFilter.Descriptor.Scope);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

You need to register it on the `ConfigureServices` of your startup class:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IFilterProvider, OverrideFriendlyFilterProvider>());
```

With all this pieces you will be able to override the authorization filter (or any other filter).

For example in the default HomeController of a new mvc application, any logged in user will be able to access the **Home** action, but only the ones with the admin role will be able to access the **About** action:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin"), OverrideAuthorization]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Spent a couple days of tinkering and writing hacky code until I found this which solved all my problems.
Note that `.RemoveAll` no longer exists (or maybe I just don't have it available on my end). Instead, I had to get a list of the filters to remove and remove them individually in a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use the new policy based authorization approach instead of using roles directly.

There is not a lot of documentation yet about policy based authorization but [this article](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/) is a good start